# How to close application before its fully loaded?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to prevent MainForm from loading fully during the process of starting up an application (not sure how its called, Component Initialization maybe)?

I've tried:

```
public MainForm()
{
    if (true)
    {
        Application.Exit();
        return;
    }
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and

```
public MainForm()
{
    if (true)
    {
        this.Close();
        Application.Exit();
        return;
    }
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and without "return;" as well.

The first one does actually nothing, while the second solution throws up an "Cannot access a disposed object." error?

Is it even possible to close whole Application before its fully loaded?

Just to make it clear I want to prevent application from loading in case of database connection issue.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to check for database connectivity prior to calling the constructor for the main form?

Such as having a "loading" splash screen which checks all prerequisites to the application functioning.  If any check fails it can abort at that point.  If all checks pass, the main form can load.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, while I haven't considered this at all. That would be probably best solution to my general problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `Environment.Exit` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

As ho1 said, `Environment.Exit` is the answer. For example:

```
public MainForm()
{
    if (true)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

That will cause the application to close if the condition is `true` in the if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer given by rob_g is the way to go.  Having the database initialized and validated prior to showing the form is the neatest solution in my opinion!  You also remove unnecessary logic from the form constructor, as the form shouldnt really care about db initialization.

Comment: As I said below the Question it is probably the best solution to the general problem, that I'm going to develop.